# How to display data from two tables code first EF ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to display data from two tables which are join with foreign key.
My models:

```
public class Deal
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Client name")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    // FK
    public virtual ICollection<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
// GET: Deal
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Deals);
}
```

How can I display in View something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NazwaKlienta)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Nazwisko)!!!
    </td>
</tr>}
```

I always get error `Invalid column name 'Discriminator'.
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.User.Nazwisko)`

Comment: create a new class with the properties needed for the view ( view model) and read data from 2 tables and assign properties of this class. make your view strongly typed to this view model.  There are a lot of examples in SO.

Comment: Google _Invalid column name 'Discriminator'._ and you will find lots of potential solutions to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ViewModel which contains properties of both tables, you can assign the entities' values to the viewmodel's properties and eventually show it.

For example:

```
public class Deal
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Client name")]
    public string ClientName { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModelTest
{
   public int DealId { get; set; }
   public string ClientName { get; set; }
   public string UserId { get; set; }

   public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

If you write some code that will assign the entity values to the properties of the ViewModel, you are able to show both entities using a viewmodel.